# How to change keyboard layout in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

Before you downvote this for being a stupid question, bear with me here. I installed Windows 10 in English, with standard US keyboard layout. However, I created my own keyboard layout which is a US layout with possibility of entering my native language specific characters when I press
`alt gr + []\;'` for small letters and `alt gr + shift + []\;'` for the capitals. I've then gone into language options and deleted the standard US keyboard layout, leaving only my own.

However, if I were to fat-finger `win+space` it would switch back to the US layout I have removed and which does not exist. I can hit it again to revert, but it's really annoying and I'd rather have it not happen at all.

In hopes of turning it off, I went into keyboard settings and input language hot keys. This shortcut isn't there, but I've disabled both of ones the ones that are (for switching between input languages, and for switching between my keyboard layout and the standard US keyboard layout that doesn't exist).

After a while of searching, I've discovered [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys). While I can't outright disable the shortcut with this, I can remap `win+space` to something like `space` so even if I do fat-finger it, it doesn't change the language, it instead makes a change I can detect right away and correct. I did all this last night and I've been using my PC most of the day today.

In two instances, my keyboard somehow, yet again, switched to standard US layout that doesn't exists.

So, I've disabled keyboard shortcut for switching between the two layouts (in the keyboard settings) and remapped the one that I couldn't disable.

So, what other ways are there to switch between the keyboard layouts that are simple enough that one could do them without noticing?

Or are there some situations where Windows 10 would, as it does for more and more things these days, assume that it knows what I want better than myself and go and change the layout on my behalf?